# FTP download capped per file

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I noticed something that is only happening on one of my computers. When I connect to my server (I'm in US, server is in EU), individual file downloads are capped to 1.8Mb/s

Comment: The path taken to that server (especially one that far away) may have an effect on download speeds.

Comment: All the computers I'm testing with are behind the same router. I don't think they would take a different route to the server, would they? the traceroute shows the same path.

Comment: If trace route shows exactly the same path from your local network to that specific server every time, and your other machines are able to transfer files faster than the "capped" one, then it seems unlikely to be the path itself.